# How to navigate from main page to login page in nativescript vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, routes, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to make it so as I can interchange **Login Page** <-> **Signup Page**
If either is successful then I want to go to **App Page**

**In App Component**

```
logout(){
    this.$navigateTo(Router["/Login"].component , {
        clearHistory: true
    }); //returns createcomment and doesnot navigate 
}
```

However, this only returns *createcomment* in the terminal.

This has to do with navigation stack but I don't know how to make it work as there is no documentation on this.

When I logout to **Signup Page** it works but not on **Login Page**

```
logout(){
    this.$navigateTo(Router["/Signup"].component , {
        clearHistory: true
    }); //navigates fine
}
```

Is it because I have LoginPage on my main.ts??

```
render: h => h('frame', [h(Login)])
```

> I am using nativescript-vue with typescript and class-components. Also I have manual routers. And as you have guessed I am relatively new to both Vuejs and NS

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample?

Comment: @Manoj idk if I can use Vue-property-decorator in playground.

Answer (score -2):

Vue Router (Unsupported)
Currently, integration with Vue Router is unsupported. Until the team resolves the issue, please use manual routing.
See https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/vue-router/

Comment: You have do Manual the router

Comment: I clearly and obviously am aware of that fact and I am using manual routing.